# Magento - How to hide blocks when viewed on mobile?

Tags: magento, mobile, hide, block

on my site's (www.adventwatches.com) mobile responsive theme, I would like to hide certain blocks when viewed on mobile. How do I go about doing it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the block by CSS

```
  /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) -------*/
  @media only screen 
  and (min-device-width : 320px) 
  and (max-device-width : 480px) {
   .your-block-class{
         display: none;
         visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

to get more information about media query refer this link 
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/